# How to write Python program illustrating chaotic behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, chaos

When I run the program below, it outputs all the numbers as 0.0. How can  fix this to illustrate chaotic behaviour?

```
# A simple program illustrating chaotic behaviour

def main():
    print ("This program illustrates a chaotic function")
    x = int (float(input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: ")))
    for i in range(10):
        x = 3.9 * x * (1-x)
        print (x)

main()
```

Comment: Python's `int()` floors numbers so every number between 0 and 1 rounds to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line where you get input, you take the number and make it an integer. Making something an integer removes all decimals. When you type in ‘0.54’, then the `int` function takes off the decimals leaving just 0.

If you just do `x = float(input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: "))` then it will work.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Actually u have a +1 or - 1 in end will help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please elaborate more on your answer?

Comment: elaborate your question